# override Magento getQty with custom module

Tags: module, magento-1, inventory

I would like to override the inventory set in Magento with my own custom inventory coming from our ERP. I had to do something similar with getPrice, but I can't seem to find the getQty function in Mage.

Any help locating it and setting a base amount would be most helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Magento has a whole module about inventory: `Mage_CatalogInventory`, the class which is the stock qty is `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item` and it has a `qty` property and field in the database.

All the stuff about checking the available qty and increasing/decreasing it happens in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer`